# Android : Custom DatePicker select only Future Date

Tags: android

i want to be set month from the year in the datePicker.

my date picker is start from today date. i want to set that any one can select only future date.

example : if today date is 05-09-2016 than year start from 2016 and go on.
month start from 09 ans show only 9,10,11,12 and if i select year 2017 then month show 1-to-12.

Comment: Use the `setMinDate()` method of `DatePicker`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify minDate as today by adding `minDate: 0` to the options

```
$("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    ...
});
```

[Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/2CZtV/1372/)

Comment: private void initMonthPickerView(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, minYear + yearPos);
        String year = yearList.get(0);
     
      int  cyear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (cyear==minYear) {
           int monthCount = 12 - minMonth;
           int j;
           for (j = 0; j <= monthCount; j++) {
               monthList.add(format2LenStr(j + minMonth));

           }

           monthLoopView.setDataList((ArrayList) monthList);
           monthLoopView.setInitPosition(monthPos);
       }

Comment: if i select year= 2016 then month start from 9.

Comment: and if i select year is 2017 and more then month start from 1